# Unable to install package in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pip, ssl-certificate

I have a project build on python 2.7 and can't install any package got SSL error

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package_name>
```

Comment: virtualenv error.

Comment: create new virtualenv.